# Use HTML-template from other app, in same project (Django)

Tags: django

I have a project which contains two apps `User` and `Accounting`. Since all of their HTML-templates should extend from the same `base.html` template, I made a third app called `Shared`, and my `accounting/base.html` and `user/base.html` would then extend from `shared/base.html` like

```html
{% extends "shared/base.html" %}


{% block content %}
<div>Hello world</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

but that does not work, since Django looks in `<app>/templates/shared/base.html`.

Can this be done without having to just duplicate `base.html` and have the same file in `Accounting` and `User`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have all apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` for such template lookups.

Otherwise Django does not know that is supposed to look in `templates` folder inside `shared` app.

Comment: Of course! What a silly mistake